# Bootstrap 3 - Columns in row should have same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a view with 4 articles within a colored box.
When the screen is wide enough they need to be displayed side by side and have the same height like this:

```
Article 1       Article 2
Article 3       Article 4
```

I have tried adding the style so the container - row and columns have following style, but to no result either:

```
.container-height{
display:table;
}

.row-height{
display:table-row;
}

.col-height{
display:table-cell;
float:none;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/vrlHw8tepKZ5nj4SW8EB?p=preview

Comment: 4 column in 1 row with same height??

Comment: 2 side by side, my bad in the question, will modify

Comment: Why not give your `<article>` tag a class and set its fixed height via CSS?

Comment: try using [min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

Comment: so it have to be 4 col in one row with 2 top then 2 bottom or 2 row with 2 col each inside like your demo?

Comment: might as well set a fixed height then, it needs to be responsive on layout changes and resize to the biggest size of the row. Want to get this done in css and not rely on javascript

Comment: @HenryVarrolike the demo

Comment: @JMan check my answer please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: you can use min-height property for every column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are ok with jquery solution then please have a look at this code.

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/e167jpb8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var heightNew = 0;
    $('.col-md-6 article').each(function(index, element) {
        if($(this).height() > heightNew){
            heightNew = $(this).height();
        }
        $(this).css('height', heightNew+'px');
    });
});
```

so just add this in  tag and  use this css.

```
article{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:lightgray;
    margin:0 25px 50px 25px;
}
h1, p{
    padding:10px;
}
```

What i did is, i took max-height of article and give that height to other so who ever is the biggest article, all article will be the same height. Hope you will like my idea. Thank you

Comment: Can't we do it with css only?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal m not sure. That's why i added that if you are ok with jquery. But with css, i don't think it will be possible as content will increase in any article will lead to different height..

Comment: it is possible with css if he change a bit of html structure...but this also works of he can use jquery

Comment: Well m sorry but m not sure its possible with css(and busy in office so i can't give much time) but if you have any better solution then please post. I will learn too :)

Comment: this is a working solution i also got, but i'm trying to get a css solution

Comment: I will try to do with css and will update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

getting them along side each other can be achieved by using the bootstrap class
col-lg-6 in the case of 2 cols this adds up to 12 and only be active on a large screen (from 1200px and up)

the quickest way to get the equal height for all of the columns (in case of fixed content) is by setting the height, making use of a media query

`@media(min-width: 1200){
  height: xx;
}`

Comment: Could be a possibility, but then whenever the contents change a recalculation is required for the good height

Answer (score 0):

**If you using Bootstrap.** This code very helpfull for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row  row-eq-height">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Header 1 </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sdfdfdit amet, duo latine euismod ut. Nullam lobortis nec cu, vel nisl simul at. Ad pro omnis quando suavitate, est ea quod autem perfecto, eros brute nusquam pri ut. At saepe dicant euismod nec.. Lorem ipsum dolor sdfdfdit amet, duo latine euismod ut. Nullam lobortis nec cu, vel nisl simul at. Ad pro omnis quando suavitate, est ea quod autem perfecto, eros brute nusquam pri ut. At saepe dicant euismod nec..</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Header 1 </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit fdfdfamet, duo latine euismod ut. Nullam lobortis nec cu, vel nisl simul at. Ad pro omnis quando suavitate, est ea quod autem perfecto, eros brute nusquam pri ut. At saepe dicant euismod nec..</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Header 1 </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sidfdft amet, duo latine euismod ut. Nullam lobortis nec cu, vel nisl simul at. Ad pro omnis quando suavitate, est ea quod autem perfecto, eros brute nusquam pri ut. At saepe dicant euismod nec..</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Header 1 </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit afgfmet, duo latine euismod ut. Nullam lobortis nec cu, vel nisl simul at. Ad pro omnis quando suavitate, est ea quod autem perfecto, eros brute nusquam pri ut. At saepe dicant euismod nec..</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: wish that could be that simple, but have you see his demo? he want that way - two row, with two col inside each

Comment: But it is possible to put the `equal height` class on the cols, see bootstrap docs [docs](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)